# Unexpected Token . when running server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm currently writing a web application with the MEAN stack, and am testing to see if my nodejs server is working. Here's my server.js:

```
    // server.js
    'use strict';

    // modules =================================================
    const path = require('path');
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const methodOverride = require('method-override');

    // configuration ===========================================

    // config files
    const db = require('./config/db');

    // set our port
    var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

    // connect to mongoDB
    // (uncomment after entering in credentials in config file)
    // mongoose.connect(db.url);

    // get all data/stuff of the body (POST) parameters
    // parse application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));

    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request simulate DELETE/PUT
    app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));

    // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    // routes ==================================================
    require('./app/routes')(app); // configure our routes

    // start app ===============================================
    // startup our app at http://localhost:8080
    app.listen(port);

    // shoutout to the user
    console.log('App running on port ' + port);

    // expose app
    exports = module.exports = app;
```

I currently have it redirecting all routes to my index.html file to test to make sure my views are working. Here's my routes.js:

```
    // models/routes.js

    // grab the user model
    var User = require('./models/user.js');

    module.exports = {
        // TODO: Add all routes needed by application

        // frontend routes =========================================================
        // route to handle all angular requests
        app.get('*', function(req, res) {
            res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load our public/index.html  file
        });
    };
```

However, when I try to run `node server.js`, it gives me this error:

```
    /home/hess/Projects/FitTrak/app/routes.js
        app.get('*', function(req, res) {
           ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this? I checked and all my braces and parentheses are all closed and written correctly.

Comment: You're building a bad object literal. module.exports = { key : 'value' } is good.

Comment: I'm assuming you may want to do something like : module.exports = function(app) { /* your code */}

Comment: We don't do SOLVED in the title here. If you answered your question, either post the answer and mark it as accepted or delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

As [Jose Hermosilla Rodrigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3866134/jose-hermosilla-rodrigo) said in his comment, you're declaring the object literal `module.exports` wrong. It should look like this instead:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load our public/index.html  file
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

just try this code...

// models/routes.js

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();

// TODO: Add all routes needed by application

        // frontend routes =========================================================
        // route to handle all angular requests
 app.get('*', function(req, res) {
            res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
        });

module.exports = route;
```

server.js

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var route=require('./models/route.js');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');

// configuration ===========================================

// config files
const db = require('./config/db');

// set our port
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// connect to mongoDB
// (uncomment after entering in credentials in config file)
// mongoose.connect(db.url);

// get all data/stuff of the body (POST) parameters
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request simulate DELETE/PUT
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));

// set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// routes ==================================================
require('./app/routes')(app); // configure our routes

// start app ===============================================
// startup our app at http://localhost:8080
app.listen(port);

// shoutout to the user
console.log('App running on port ' + port);


 app.use('/',route);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MEAN stack I would suggest you to use express own router middleware to handle all your routes. Just include.

```
var router = express.Router();
    //use router to handle all your request
    router.get(/xxx,function(req, res){
    res.send(/xxxx);
    })

   // You may have n number of router for all your request
   //And  at last all you have to do is export router

     module.exports = router;
```